# Oracle Declare variable and use it in another select query

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

New to oracle/toad.

I am defining a variable and inserting its value from select into. After setting its value I am using it into another select statement. But this gives me error and INTO clause is expected in this SELECT

```
declare  maxLineNo number := 0;

BEGIN
select Max(b.Line_No) into maxLineNo  FROM  Brokerage b   WHERE b.External_App_Id = 3720     AND b.Account_Id = '16970' ;

SELECT b.External_App_Id   -- this select giving erro
         , maxLineNo + 1
         , b.Currency
         , ''
         , CAST( SUM(b.Brokerage_Amt) as VARCHAR2(17))
         , ''
         , ''
         , 1003  -- 1003 for Report summary
         , ''
    FROM  Brokerage b
   WHERE b.External_App_Id = 3720 
   GROUP BY External_App_Id, B.CURRENCY
   ORDER BY 2; 

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(maxLineNo);  -- this is giving value
end;
```

Comment: within PL/SQL block , `SELECT` works only with `INTO` clause

Comment: so what do you suggest? If the close the block, var MaxLineNo won't available to use outside.

Comment: Also, it's better to write `NULL`  instead of ''  for blank values.

Comment: Since the above won't even compile due to the missing INTO clause in the second SELECT I have a feeling that you're seeing something which isn't related to this. Change your DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE to `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Test #1: ' || maxLineNo);` and see what you get. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are searching for [Implicit Statement Results in Oracle Database 12c Release 1](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/implicit-statement-results-12cr1):

```
declare  
  maxLineNo number := 0;
  rc sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
select Max(b.Line_No) into maxLineNo
 FROM  Brokerage b
WHERE b.External_App_Id = 3720     AND b.Account_Id = '16970' ;

open rc for
SELECT b.External_App_Id   -- this select giving erro
         , ''
         , b.Currency
         , ''
         , CAST( SUM(b.Brokerage_Amt) as VARCHAR2(17))
         , ''
         , ''
         , 1003  -- 1003 for Report summary
         , ''
    FROM  Brokerage b
   WHERE b.External_App_Id = 3720 
   GROUP BY External_App_Id, B.CURRENCY
   ORDER BY 2; 

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(maxLineNo);  -- this is giving value

dbms_sql.return_result(rc);
end;
```